# want crousal like attached image in ios ipad application

Tags: ios, ipad, scroll, paging

I want crousal animation for ipad application. I have attached animation image. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) or [SwiftCarousel](https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/SwiftCarousel). You can create your own control via `UICollectionView` with custom layout. But in my opinion, its better to use open source library.